# How retrieve an index of an NSArray using a NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsarray

I would know how retrieve an index of an `NSArray` using a `NSPredicate` ?

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"New-York City",
                  @"Washington DC",
                  @"Los Angeles",
                  @"Detroit",
                  nil];
```

Which kind of method should I use in order to get the index of "Los Angles" by giving only a `NSString`?
NB: `@"Los An"` or `@"geles"` should return the same index.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using NSPredicate you can get array of strings that contain your search string (it seems there's no built-in method to get just element indexes):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

You can get only indexes using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` method:

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
   NSString *s = (NSString*)obj;
   NSRange range = [s rangeOfString: searchString];
   return range.location != NSNotFound;
}];
```

If you want to get just one element containing your string you can use similar `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` method for that.

Comment: @wagashi, uh thanks, wrong property name. Funny you're the first to spot an error - after 7 month :)

Comment: :) By the way, it should be "^BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)"

Answer (score 21):

You should be able to do this with blocks. Below is a snippet (I don't have a compiler handy so pls excuse any typos):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              @"New-York City",
              @"Washington DC",
              @"Los Angeles",
              @"Detroit",
              nil];
NSString *matchCity = @"Los";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", matchCity];
NSUInteger index = [self.array  indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                return [predicate evaluateWithObject:obj];
                   }];
```

Essentially you can use the indexOfObjectPassingTest: method. This takes a block (code following the "^") and returns the index for the first object that matches your predicate (or NSNotFound if no match exists). The block iterates through each object in the array until either a match is found (at which point it returns the index) or no match is found (at which point it returns NSNotFound). Here is a link to block programming that can help you understand the logic within the block:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/

Answer (score 3):

Found an alternative approach helpful where the search is more complex as it allows predicate to be used to find object then object to find index:

```
-(NSIndexPath*) indexPathForSelectedCountry{
    NSUInteger indexToCountry = 0;
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isoCode = %@",self.selectedCountry.isoCode];
    NSArray * selectedObject = [self.countryList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (selectedObject){
        if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive){
            indexToCountry = [self.searchResults indexOfObject:selectedObject[0]];
        }else{
            indexToCountry = [self.countryList indexOfObject:selectedObject[0]];
        }
    }
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToCountry inSection:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this..

```
NSString * stringToCompare = @"geles";
int foundInIndex;

for ( int i=0; i<[array count]; i++ ){

    NSString * tryString = [[array objectAtIndex:i] description];

    if ([tryString rangeOfString:stringToCompare].location == NSNotFound) {
        // no match
    } else {
        //match found
        foundInIndex = i;
    }



}// end for loop
```

Comment: let me make some comments: 1) if there's no element matching string then your foundInIndex will remain uninitialized and you cannot use it. 2) you can get better performance using fast-enumeration or block-based enumeration 3) there's no sense to use -description method here 4) be aware that your code will find last element in array that contains search string

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Louie answer, instead of using for loop i had used enumeration block which worked for me.

I did this :-

```
NSString *stringToCompare = @"xyz";

[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id *Obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
 NSString * tryString = [[myArray objectAtIndex:idx] description];

    if ([tryString rangeOfString:stringToCompare].location == NSNotFound) {

                // no match found

         } else {

                //match found and perform your operation. In my case i had removed array object at idx

           }
        }];
```

Comment: The Vladimir solution seems more straightforward for finding indexes than this.