# Get index (for UICollectionView) from an Array of Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios7, uicollectionview, nspredicate, nsindexset

I have a `UICollectionView` that I am populating with a nested array to help me create sections in my UICollectionView. The final array that I use to populate my `UICollectionView` looks like this with each nested array representing a different section in my view:

```
 Array
    Array
       Dictionary
          txt
          utc
          ...
       Dictionary
          txt
          utc
          ...
    Array
       Dictionary
          txt
          utc
          ...
```

I want the user to be able filter the collections view based on the txt (or other elements of the dictionary) and then animate the changes in the view using `- (void)insertItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths;` or `- (void)deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths;`.

***Where I need help***

I am stuck trying to create the `NSArray` of `NSIndexSets` that I need for the methods I mentioned above. It seems like `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` of `NSIndexSets` would be involved but I can not get it to work properly and any examples I can find are typically just for a single array ([How retrieve an index of an NSArray using a NSPredicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231299/how-retrieve-an-index-of-an-nsarray-using-a-nspredicate)) and I have not been able to adjust the code for my purposes.

Any code to help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to create the NSArray by nesting for loops (which I am not that excited about doing) but it works. If you have any more efficient way to create the array please do let me know!

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfIndexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [finalCellData count]; i++) {

        for (int ii = 0; ii < [[finalCellData objectAtIndex:i] count]; ii++) {

            if (![[[[finalCellData objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:ii]valueForKey:@"txt"] isEqualToString:@""]) {

                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:ii inSection:i];
                [arrayOfIndexes addObject:indexPath];
            }
        }
    }
```